# Scraping Javascript using Selenium via Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape javascript data from a site. Currently I'm given myself the challenge of trying to scrape the number of Followers from [this website](http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/). Here's my code so far:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chromedriver = "/Users/INSERT USERNAME/Desktop/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/")
time.sleep(5)

title = driver.find_element_by_class_name
print title
```

As you can see, I've got a chromedriver file located on my desktop. When I execute the code, I get the following result:

```
<bound method WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="dd9e5d3f429bc2810c30ebe7067e4e22")>>
```

I tried iterating into this with a for loop but it returned an error. Does anyone know how I can get the Javascript data and ultimately get the number of followers?

**EDIT:**

So as per request, I have changed my code to this:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chromedriver = "/Users/INSERT USERNAME/Desktop/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/")
time.sleep(5)

title = driver.find_element_by_class_name("member-title")
print title
```

But I now get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\INSERT USERNAME\Desktop\blogger_v.1.py", line 11, in <module>
    title = driver.find_element_by_class_name("member-title")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 413, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"member-title"}
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Any ideas on how I can get around it?

**EDIT:**

So I've changed my code to this:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chromedriver = "/Users/INSERT USERNAME/Desktop/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://freelegalconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk/")
time.sleep(5)

title = driver.find_element_by_class_name("item-title")
print title
```

And I get this result:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="5fe8fb966edd26fdf808da07f99d4109", element="0.9924860218635834-1")>
```

How would I go about just printing all the javascript? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the class name you're looking for as a parameter.

`title = driver.find_element_by_class_name("TheNameOfTheClass")`

Comment: If I wanted to print all the javascript data, do you know how I would go about doing that?